# es6 addeventlistener - Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an addEventListener arrow function where on  click of a button it changes the color by toggling a class. that looks like below:

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("clicker");

clickButton.addEventListener("click", => () {
  this.classList.toggle("modified");
}, false);
```

In my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.

Where it gets interesting is that converting this to a stand JS function like below:

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("clicker");

clickButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("modified");
});
```

Works perfectly. I don't understand why the arrow function version renders classList undefined.

How does `classList` work in ES6 arrow functions?

Comment: Why not write it as `clickButton.classList.toggle` directly, since you already have the reference to the button?

Comment: You can, but I wanted to post a Q&A now that I know `this` works differently with arrow functions.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice you'd answered your own question. Your question seems misleading since you asked `How does classList work in ES6 arrow functions?` and the answer is "exactly the same as how arrows work everywhere else". The question you answered is "why doesn't this classList call work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions in this context don't bind `this` to the element, it's bound lexically. As a result in the arrow function example since `this` isn't bound to the clicker element that is why the arrow function doesn't work, but the regular function does.

https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc

http://wesbos.com/arrow-function-no-no/

Answer (score 2):

One way to "Workaround" this is using `e.currentTarget` instead of suggested as by Ori Dori's comment

```
clickButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("modified");
}, false);
```

As cited by [Wesbos](http://wesbos.com/arrow-function-no-no/#comment-104743)

> Use currentTarget instead of target as target can change if you have
>   nested elements like a span inside a link

Answer (score 0):

Use event target like below

```
 var clickButton = document.getElementById("clicker");
 clickButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
     e.target.classList.toggle("modified") 
 });
```